# Is there a fundamental way to prove Generalized Mean is a increasing function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, statistics

Generalized mean:
$$M_k=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{{x_i}^k}{n}\right)^{\frac 1 k}$$

I try to prove $L=\ln\left(M_k\right)$ is increasing. $$\frac{d\left(L\right)}{dk}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}^k\ln\left(x_i\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}^k}$$ and I stuck here. I visited wikipedia and it says this can be proved using Jesen's inequality. But I want a simple one(or complicated one, if one think using Jesen's inequality is more easier).

Any help is going to be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is anything known about $x_i$?

Comment: @Vlad $x_i$ are real numbers.

Comment: Do you want to prove this for all integers $k$ or only positive integers $k$?  Also, if the $x_i$ are all equal then $M_k$ is a constant function of $k$, I believe.

Comment: @Rori  k is a  variable on $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: I suppose $x_i > 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer♦ I don't know whether it's true when $x_i$ are negative. But it's good enough to prove it  when $x_i$ are positive. And so sorry for forgetting to mention that $x_i$ are positive numbers. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: With negative $x_i$, $M_k$ need not be real if $k$ is not an integer. And with $k < 0$ we also need to exclude $x_i = 0$. I hadn't thought that all through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jensen's inequality, it is indeed easy.

- In the first place, suppose $0 <k<\ell$, and consider the function $f$ defined by $\;f(x)=x^{\tfrac \ell k}$. As $\dfrac\ell k >1$, this function is convex, so by *Jensen's inequality*,
  $$\biggl(\frac{x_1^k+\dots+x_n^k}n\biggr)^{\!\tfrac\ell k}\le\frac{\bigl(x_1^k\bigr)^{\tfrac\ell k}+\dots+\bigl(x_n^k\bigr)^{\tfrac\ell k}}n=\frac{x_1^\ell+\dots+x_n^\ell}n$$
  Raising both sides to the power $\dfrac1\ell$, we obtain
  $$ M_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\biggl(\frac{x_1^k+\dots+x_n^k}n\biggr)^{\!\tfrac1 k}\le\biggl(\frac{x_1^\ell+\dots+x_n^\ell}n\biggr)^{\!\tfrac1\ell} =M_\ell(x_1,\dots,x_n).$$
- Suppose now $k<0<\ell$, and set $k=-k'$. We'll prove
  $$\Biggl(\frac{x_1^{-k'}+\dots+x_n^{-k'}}n\Biggr)^{\!\!-\tfrac1{k'}}\le\bigl(x_1\cdots x_n\bigr)^{\tfrac1n}\le\Biggl(\frac{x_1^{\ell}+\dots+x_n^{\ell}}n\Biggr)^{\!\!\tfrac1{\ell}}. $$
  The left-hand inequality is equivalent to
  $$\Biggl(\frac1n\biggl(\frac1{x_1^{k'}}+\dots+\frac1{x_n^{k'}}\biggr)\Biggr)^{\!\!-1}\le\Bigl(x_1^{k'}\cdots x_n^{k'}\Bigr)^{\tfrac1n}$$
  which is the *harmonic-geometric means inequality*.

The right-hand inequality is equivalent to the *arithmetic-geometric means inequality:*
$$\bigl(x_1^{\ell}\cdots x_n^{\ell}\bigr)^{\tfrac1n}\le\frac{x_1^{\ell}+\dots+x_n^{\ell}}n. $$

- The last case $k<\ell<0$ is easy: setting $k=-k',\ \ell=-\ell'$, it steps back to the first case.

Comment: It seems that you made a typo mistake. $\dfrac\ell l >1$ should be $\dfrac\ell k >1$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you for pointing it!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bernard's solution, here is my proof using wikipedia notation for power mean: $\bar x(m) = ({1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^m)^{1\over m}$
[image]